# How to write automation script using selenium webdriver in JMeter for file upload in dropzone?

Tags: selenium, file-upload, jmeter, drag-and-drop, load-testing

I have developed one selenium webdriver script in JMeter. My script is running well but it stuck at one scenario. I am not able to upload/file/files in Dropzone from my system.
I tried below code but it is not working. What is right way to do that with Java/Javascript-Selenium in JMeter.

```
 var chooseFile = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("formImportFilesDropZone"));
   WDS.browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   chooseFile.sendKeys("C:\Users\RIDE.txt");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape the back slashes with another instance of backslash like:

```
chooseFile.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\RIDE.txt");
```

or just use forward slashes:

```
chooseFile.sendKeys("C:/Users/RIDE.txt");
```

You may also need to specify fully qualified class name for the [TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) like:

```
WDS.browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

More information:

- [JavaScript Strings](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Also get used to look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), normally it contains if not the reason of failure or misbehaviour but at least a clue.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but it's not working. No change in the script. Error is org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable.

Comment: 1) Is the file name and path correct? Would be great to add a screenshot of the file (displaying file path as well). Just thinking, it could be some upper case/lower case character issue in the file path.

Comment: Path and name both are right.

Comment: Ooppss. I missed your first comment. It clearly says that element which you trying to select is not interactable. Looks like the file upload element do not have a upload button (dropzone has a different way of implementing it) as normally we see in general cases. You might have to consider a different approach in this case.

Comment: Ya, how to implement it for dropzone?. I have done it successfully with python and robot framework but here I need it with Javascript as it is in JMeter.

Comment: You can try clicking that element using selenium click() method. You can use the below example
var button = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.cssSelector('button.button-search'))
button.click()

Comment: On clicking dropzone it opens windows explorer to select the file but cant select files as its windows. There should be something which will directly add the file in dropzone as we do it in python-robotframework.

Answer (score 0):

Once window explorer is opened, you can use send Keys method to send the path of the file and then again use send Keys method to send Enter key.

Comment: That is not working.